# What is wrong in follwing -exec command

Tags: command-line, find

I m getting error in follwing command

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/EspoCRM-2.5.2 && find data -type d -exec chmod 775 {}
```

error:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to mark your exec as finished with `\;`
Your command would look like:

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/EspoCRM-2.5.2 && find data -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

BTW: You don't need to cd into a dir. find can take a complete path where to search. So

```
find /opt/lampp/htdocs/EspoCRM-2.5.2/data/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

should also work as find call.

Comment: still I am getting same  error

Comment: Command is working. Ensure, everything is correct with your path.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, find's `-exec` needs to be terminated. However I would actually suggest using `+` instead of `\;`. This only works for some commands but using `+` will build and run a much more efficient command.

For example, if you have three files (`a`, `b` and `c`) in a directory and you run `find -exec echo {} \;` it will execute:

```
echo a
echo b
echo c
```

However, if you use `find -exec echo {} +` it will dynamically select as many arguments as the environment supports (there is a limit) and, like `xargs` chains them together... So what is actually run is:

```
echo a b c
```

As I said before this will only work if your command supports multiple files at a time. `chmod` is one of this. You can tell by looking at the `man chmod` page:

```
SYNOPSIS
       chmod [OPTION]... MODE[,MODE]... FILE...
       chmod [OPTION]... OCTAL-MODE FILE...
       chmod [OPTION]... --reference=RFILE FILE...
```

The ellipsis on `FILE...` means it can take more than one file.

So yeah, chaining them all together means we run much fewer instances of `chmod` which is good because there's quite a large overhead (on small operations like this) for forking out a new command.

In short, using `+` is faster.

Answer (score 1):

You need to end your command with `\;`

Try this:

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/EspoCRM-2.5.2 && find data -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```